# Hasse's classification of Quaternion algebras (over number fields)

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quaternions

I am looking for the reference to **Hasse's original publication** classifying the Quaternion algebras over a number field $K$.  The statement in the paper or book should read something like:

``Two Quaternion algebras over a number field $K$ are isomorphic iff they are ramified at the same number of places"

Comment: Ramification is for quaternion algebras over number fields, not over arbitrary fields?

Comment: oops corrected the question

Comment: Theorem 4.8. [here](http://wkchan.web.wesleyan.edu/quaternion-2012.pdf) says:"Let $H$ and $H'$ be quaternion algebras over a number field $F$. Then $H\cong H'$ if and only if  $Ram(H) = Ram(H')$.

Comment: It says $H_v = H \otimes_K K_v$, or $H_v$ is a division algebra (and $v$ is said ramified) or $H_v \cong M_2(K_v)$. Theorem 1.13 says it is about the equation $ax^2+by^2=1, (x,y) \in K_v$ where $H=K[i,j], i^2=a,j^2=b,ij = -ji$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Hasse_invariant), Hasse introduced an invariant, now known as the Hasse invariant in two papers ([here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01457954) and [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01448916)) to classify central simple algebras.

Comment: In particular, for rank $4$ (quaternion algebras), the local invariant is either $0$ or $1/2$, the latter being the nonsplit (ramified) case. These local invariants must add up to $0\pmod{\Bbb Z}$. So to specify the isomorphism class it’s enough to specify which local invariants are $1/2$.